# Quarto: Can't remove TOC, LOF and LOT headings

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, quarto

[This Github repo](https://github.com/albersonmiranda/monografia),  hosts my dissertation template in Rmarkdown which I'm trying to update to Quarto. However, I can't get rid of TOC, LOT and LOF titles in qmd version.

I've tried

```
\addto\captionsportuguese{% since I'm setting Babel to Brazil
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Whatever}%
}
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}
```

and, of course, setting `toc-title: ''` in yaml with no success. It still prints "table of contents".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the `toc-title`, simple add the following in your `preamble.tex` which will remove the title.

**preamble.tex**

```
\deftocheading{toc}{}%
```

To remove `lot-title` and `lof-title` define these in quarto yaml header under `crossref` as `""`.

**monographia.qmd**

```
title: ""
format:
    pdf:
        include-in-header: config/preamble.tex
csl: config/abnt.csl
bibliography: config/bib.bib
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin=1in
spacing: onehalfspacing
crossref: 
  lot-title: ""
  lof-title: ""
```

And I am not sure why setting `toc-title` as `""` is not working in this case, but using `\deftocheading{toc}{}` definitely works.

Comment: Thanks! I should add that setting `lot-title: ""` worked for babel package, but not for polyglossia. So I added `\deftocheading{lof}{}` (and lot) instead as I moved to polyglossia.

Comment: Yes, `\deftocheading{}{}` is the ultimate move